# Centos: Add unportitioned space to root

Tags: centos, space, partitioning

My main partition mounted on / is 14GB.
The Same drive has additional 47 GB of free unpartitioned space.
How do I add the space to the root partition?

Thank you very much for your help.

df -h output:

`[root@dev-dla /]# df -h
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/centos-root   14G   13G  968M  94% /
devtmpfs                 1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                    1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                    1.9G  8.5M  1.9G   1% /run
tmpfs                    1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdb1                 99G  9.2G   85G  10% /data
/dev/sda1                497M  255M  243M  52% /boot
tmpfs                    380M     0  380M   0% /run/user/1294246044`

lsblk output:

`[root@dev-dla /]# lsblk
NAME            MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda               8:0    0   60G  0 disk
├─sda1            8:1    0  500M  0 part /boot
└─sda2            8:2    0 15.5G  0 part
  ├─centos-root 253:0    0 13.9G  0 lvm  /
  └─centos-swap 253:1    0  1.6G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
sdb               8:16   0  100G  0 disk
└─sdb1            8:17   0  100G  0 part /data
sr0              11:0    1 1024M  0 rom`

parted print free output:

`(parted) print free
Model: VMware Virtual disk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 64.4GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags:
Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
        32.3kB  1049kB  1016kB           Free Space
 1      1049kB  525MB   524MB   primary  xfs          boot
 2      525MB   17.2GB  16.7GB  primary               lvm
        17.2GB  64.4GB  47.2GB           Free Space`

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer myself. Took a little while. The solution as follows:

Create Partition:
`[$]# fdisk /dev/sda
Command (m for help): n
Partition type:
   p   primary (2 primary, 0 extended, 2 free)
   e   extended
Select (default p): p
Partition number (3,4, default 3): 3
First sector (33554432-125829119, default 33554432):
Using default value 33554432
Last sector, +sectors or +size{K,M,G} (33554432-125829119, default 125829119):
Using default value 125829119
Partition 3 of type Linux and of size 44 GiB is set
Command (m for help): w
The partition table has been altered!`

Initialize the partition:
`[$]# pvcreate /dev/sda3`

Extend Volume:
`[$]# vgextend centos /dev/sda3`

Extend Partition:
`[$]# lvextend /dev/centos/root /dev/sda3`

Resize Partition:
`[$]# xfs_growfs /dev/centos/root`